# Adding means and confidence intervals

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, confidence-interval

I have fitted a multiple regression model and prediected two samples output, y1 and y2 and their confidence interval (y1+/-k1 and y2+/-k2 ). Now I want to add these two as Z = y1+y2. But how do I represent the 95% confidence interval of Z. Will it be like Z-k1-k2 and Z+k1+k2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. First you must separate the limits of the confidence interval, $k_1$ and $k_2$, in to the product of a *critical value* and a *standard deviation*. Information on how you computed the confidence interval is necessary to provide further detail on this step.

The limits of the confidence interval for $y_1 + y_2$ will, like all other confidence intervals, take the form *critical value x standard deviation*. The *critical value* will be the same as that from your individual confidence intervals. All you need is the standard deviation of $y_1 + y_2$.

To get this, the formula is

$SD(y_1 + y_2) = \sqrt{SD(y_1)^{2} + SD(y_2)^{2} + 2 x cov(y_1,y_2)}$

Further information about your data and model will allow me to help you compute $cov(y_1,y_2)$.

To summarize, you need to:

1. Find the *critical value* used for your confidence interval- give **more information** about how you made the confidence interval for help with this
2. Find the covariance of $y_1$ and $y_2$. **More information** on your data and model is needed to help with this
3. Compute the limits by multiplying the critical value by the standard deviation, computed using the above formula